# subdirectory .rubocop.yml inherits from parent .rubocop.yml

Tags: rubocop

Inside the folder of my main application, I have another folder inside of which is a Rails Engine. I've excluded the engine subdirectory from Rubocop to avoid writing Rubocop rules from the engine into one file (parent file), but when I run Rubocop inside the subdirectory it inspects 0 files.

I don't manually inherit the parent .rubocop yml file inside the engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it inherits from the .rubocop.yml file in the parent folder. You need to run it with the `--ignore_parent_exclusion` option, which ignores all `Exclude:` settings from all .rubocop.yml files present in parent folders. Otherwise, it reachs the parent .rubocop.yml and exclude the directory you are trying to inspect.